# In Reactjs how can I do custom message for checkbox

Tags: reactjs, checkbox

**register.js**

```js
// ...other
  <Form.Check type="checkbox">
   <Form.Check.Label className={"text-muted"}>
     <Form.Check.Input type="checkbox"
      required
      onInput={(e) => {e.target.setCustomValidity('')}}
      onInvalid={(e) => {e.target.setCustomValidity(
       'Please agree to the terms and conditions!'
      )}}
      ref={(input) => {this.checkbox = input}}
     />
     <Form.Text>this is a text</Form.Text>
   </Form.Check.Label>
  </Form.Check>
  <Button variant="primary shadow-none mb-2" type="button" 
    onClick={() => {Register(this.id, this.email, this.password, this.checkbox)}}
  >
    register
   </Button>
</Form>
```

**mapDispatchToPrpos**

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
     Register(id, email, password, checkbox) {
        console.log(checkbox.checked)
        dispatch(
          actionCreators.Register(
           id.value, email.value, password.value, checkbox.checked
        ));
     }
  }
};
```

**actionCreators.js**

```js
export const Register = (id, email, password,checkbox) => {
   return (dispatch) => {
      const config = {
         method: 'post',
         url: 'http://localhost/cup/u_info.php',
         data: {
           id: id,
           email: email,
           password: password
        }
     };
     axios.request(config).then((res) => {
        const result = res.config.data;
        if (result) {
           dispatch(register());
           alert('success')
         } else {
           alert('failed')
         }
     }).catch((error) => {
         console.log(error);
     })
   }
};
```

**problem:**
I want to show my custom message when the user doesn't click the checkbox. I have already written the custom message code in the register.js, but it didn't work for me. Also you can look these execute screenshots.

**First, alert('success')**

[image]

**Second, console.log(checkbox.checked)**

[image]

I want to show my custom message when the user didn't click the checkbox and do not change another page automatically like "success".

On the contrary, I don't want to show my customer message when the user clicked the checkbox and change page automatically.